# Mocking new() in Runnable using powerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, inner-classes, powermockito

I have this class, where I'm trying to mock the object creation for UrlWrapper.class

```
public class WorkerClass {
  private final String url;

  public WorkerClass(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  void performOperation(Executor executor) throws IOException {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            UrlWrapper urlWrapper = null;
            try {
                urlWrapper = new UrlWrapper(url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlWrapper.openConnection();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    executor.execute(runnable);
  }
}
```

This is the test code which I tried

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({UrlWrapper.class, WorkerClass.class})
public class TestClass {
  @Before
  public void init() throws Exception {
    UrlWrapper urlWrapper = Mockito.mock(UrlWrapper.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(UrlWrapper.class)
                .withArguments(Mockito.anyString())
                .thenReturn(urlWrapper);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws IOException {
    Executor executor = new Executor() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Runnable command) {
            command.run();
        }
    };

    WorkerClass workerClass = new WorkerClass("");
    workerClass.performOperation(executor);
  }
}
```

But its not getting mocked. Mocking works fine without Runnable.

What Am I missing here?

Comment: Interesting question; my vote for that. Although my answer tells you to do something completely different. I hope, you will find the answer at least upvote worthy, now that you reached that level ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is **here**:

```
@PrepareForTest({UrlWrapper.class, WorkerClass.class
```

And there:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
```

Thing is: you are **not** calling *new* within the **Worker** class. You are creating an **anonymous** inner class of Worker (that Runnable instantiation) - and there you are doing the *new* call.

I see two options:

- Of course, that anonymous inner class ... actually has a class name. So, *maybe* you are able to use the "mangled" class name, and pass that to @PrepareForTest
- Avoid calling *new* this way

I rather doubt that you get the first option to work. Even if that works, it would probably be some very dirty workaround.

The **real** answer is: learn how to write **testable** code, for example by watching these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79). Your *real* problem is that call to *new*. One solution: create a **factory** that gives you URL objects; and then use dependency injection to acquire that factory in your runnable.

That factory can be mocked without PowerMock(ito) ... and all of a sudden, your whole design gets improved; at the same time it becomes easier to test.